# How to set alert dialog box in customize listview item by click long press

Tags: android, listview

I want to set songs as a ringtone or alarm tone or message tone etc in list view by long pressing the list item. I want to show an dialog box which perform these action. How to show  a dialog box by long pressing a list item and set action in dialog box? Please help me...

```
com.example.ring;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Naat extends Activity implements
        OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView listView;
    public static MediaPlayer mp;
    Button bt;
    PopAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<String> dataItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static int[] rings = {R.raw.arabicmusic, R.raw.arabicmusic1, R.raw.arabicmusic12,
            R.raw.arabicmusic13, R.raw.arabicmusic14, R.raw.arabicmusic15,
            R.raw.arabicmusic18, R.raw.arabicmusic16, R.raw.arabicmusic17};
    public static int imgadrss = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_naat);
        String[] dataArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listdata);
        List<String> dataTemp = Arrays.asList(dataArray);
        dataItems.addAll(dataTemp);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listnaat);
        //  bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        adapter = new PopAdapter(Naat.this, dataItems);
        //  adapter.setCustomButtonListner(MainActivity.this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    //  @Override
    //  public void onButtonClickListner(int position, String value) {
    //      mp.create(this, rings[position]);
    //      mp.start();
    //
    //      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button click " + value,
    //              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //
    //  }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + position, 2000).show();
        imgadrss = rings[position];
    }
}
```

Adapter class

```
com.example.ring;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NaatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    customButtonListener customListner;

    public interface customButtonListener {
        public void onButtonClickListner(int position, String value);
    }

    public void setCustomButtonListner(customButtonListener listener) {
        this.customListner = listener;

    }

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    public NaatAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> dataItem) {
        super(context, R.layout.singlerow, dataItem);
        this.data = dataItem;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singlerow, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            viewHolder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final String temp = getItem(position);
        viewHolder.text.setText(temp);
        viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (customListner != null) {
                    customListner.onButtonClickListner(position, temp);
                }
                // MainActivity.mp.create(context, MainActivity.imgadrss);
                // MainActivity.mp.start();
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, Naat.rings[position]);

                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.pause();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.start();
                    }
                }
                // mp.stop();
                Toast.makeText(context, "" + position, 2000).show();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        Button button;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                int index, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Log.d("in onLongClick");
             //Open alert dialog here
            return true;
        }
});
```

Comment: Did you import the necessary statements like

    import android.widget.AdapterView;

Comment: @ZarNoxh what kind of errors? Where did you put the code? Do you have the dialog portion of the code?